# Bower install command does not install anything

Tags: javascript, bower

I have troubles getting bower to work on Mac OS X (10.9.3).

First I made sure no older or conflicting version of bower was installed. (Code is the dir)

```
➜  Code  which bower
bower not found
➜  Code  bower
zsh: command not found: bower
```

Then I installed from scratch

```
➜  Code  npm install -g bower
/usr/local/bin/bower -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower
bower@1.3.5 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower
├── is-root@0.1.0
```

… etc …

After that, I end up with a half working bower it seems:

```
➜  test  bower lookup jQuery
jQuery git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git
➜  test  bower install jQuery
➜  test  ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   2 edwin  staff    68 Jun 18 09:59 .
drwxr-xr-x  96 edwin  staff  3264 Jun 18 09:59 ..


➜  test  bower init
➜  test
```

What could be the issue here?

Some more version info:

```
➜  test  npm -v
1.4.14
➜  test  node -v
v0.10.29
➜  test  bower -v
1.3.5
➜  test
```

Comment: What is your `$NODE_PATH` set to?

Comment: NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules

Comment: BTW - if I do `sudo bower -f --allow-root install jquery` it does install something, but this is not the way to go of course

Comment: I solved it. With the new version of bower (1.3.7) I actually got an error message which was informative enough to be able to solve it.

    bower EACCES        EACCES, permission denied '/Users/edwin/.local/share/bower/empty'

A recursive chown to make the directories my own instead of root made it work again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. With the new version of bower (1.3.7) I actually got an error message which was informative enough to be able to solve it.

```
bower EACCES        EACCES, permission denied '/Users/edwin/.local/share/bower/empty'
```

A recursive chown to make the directories my own instead of root made it work again.